# How to bindValue in array?

Tags: php, pdo, bindvalue

I have a many things to insert into database colums.

```
    $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, message, date, time, id) VALUES (:username, :password, :message, :date, :time, :id");
```

Instead of binding them all, I created a array:

```
    $IDs = array($username, $password, $message, $time, $date, $ID);
```

How do I take each variable from this array and bind it?
I am completely lost with PDO.

Comment: Just give your array items the correct keys and `execute()` the thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
$sth->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password, $message, $time, $date, $ID))
```

and for others...

Comment: No need for the colons in there. Also you are missing some parameters ;)